# Large amount of time entered as number in an Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

According to [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f#bmcalculation), the largest amount of time that can be entered in a cell and then be interpreted by Excel as a number is `9999:59:59`. My Excel experience does not contradict this limit.

**Question:** Is it possible to enter a timespan bigger than the limit and force Excel to interpret it as a number (I think of a workaround here)?

For example, if I enter `7500:12:10` in a cell, this will be interpreted as a number. But entering `12000:52:21` results in a string. When the value is interpreted as a string, no number formats are taken into consideration.

Comment: There could me multiple workarounds here, but all have their limitations. Please explain a bit broader your requirements (how big numbers do you want to store, what precision do you need, what operations do you want to perform on them...), to help us offering the best workaround,.

Comment: I have extended my question. The question can also be formulated in this way: how to enter amounts of time bigger than 9999:59:59 in an Excel cell to be interpreted as number?

Comment: ".. an Excel cell to be interpreted as number" - no way for that. That wouldn't be workaround. You can use a helper column where you convert it to desired format with formulas, or use VBA, but still your question is too broad.

Comment: Why does `7500:12:10` = `11/7/1900 12:12:10PM` and value at `312.5084491`? Give that in the details and maybe someone can discuss the problem.

Comment: Have a look at this item: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180234/hours-calculations-in-excel-2010

Comment: Useful link, saying that the value interpreted as a string can be re-interpreted to be useful in further calculations. But my question referred to the case whether this limit for time amounts can be "switch off" (that's the workaround I was thinking of) to really have a number in the cell instead of the string. I am getting more and more sure that this limit cannot be overridden.

Comment: If I understand your question, the issue is limited to entering (and/or displaying?) time in that format.  That value is a little shy of 14 months.  You can store and work with times on the order of centuries.  The workaround would just need to deal with inputting in a better format, and/or building the displayed value to look like that.

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly, my question is about this special format. Other formats may be more flexible, but because of consistency reasons I have to stick to this format.